# Questions about parameter "bestEffort:true" for reduceRegion in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

There is an imagecollection including several images. 
For a specific region, I want to do mean statistic for each image.
However, the error occurred: Too many pixels in the region.
I can set the paramter bestEffort:true to complete the computation.
But, increasing the scale may lead to the fact that the mean value is different from that of original scale.How to deal with this issue?
Looking forwarding to your instruction! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `maxPixels` argument inside `ee.Image.reduceRegion()` to a large enough value. Your error message will provide you with the number of pixels you need. Here's an example:

```
image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: myRegion,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much， it works now!